# Null finalizers not applied when creating a Persistent Volume Claim in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am performing a `kubectl apply -f jenkins_pvc.yaml` where

```
$ cat jenkins_pvc.yaml
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: "jenkins-cd-pvc"
  namespace: "jenkins"
  finalizers: null
spec:
  storageClassName: "standard"
  volumeName: "jenkins-cd-pv"
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: "200Gi"
```

however the finalizers field is not taken into account from what the pvc description indicates:

```
▶ k describe pvc jenkins-cd-pvc
Name:          jenkins-cd-pvc
Namespace:     jenkins
StorageClass:  standard
Status:        Bound
Volume:        jenkins-cd-pv
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      200Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    jenkins-cd-6d8f5c79d6-xt2fs
Events:        <none>
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

[StorageObjectInUseProtection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#storageobjectinuseprotection) plugin [adds](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/fb87f72b882abc28c7331c3d089d0c096f31dd26/plugin/pkg/admission/storage/storageobjectinuseprotection/admission.go#L129) the `kubernetes.io/pvc-protection` finalizer to newly created Persistent Volume Claims (PVCs).

You can disable this admission controller which is enabled by default.

To see which admission plugins are enabled

```
kube-apiserver -h | grep enable-admission-plugins
```

The Kubernetes API server flag `disable-admission-plugins` takes a comma-delimited list of admission control plugins to be disabled, even if they are in the list of plugins enabled by default.

```
kube-apiserver --disable-admission-plugins=StorageObjectInUseProtection
```

As a side note you can always patch a pvc after its created.

```
kubectl patch pvc PVC_NAME -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers": []}}' --type=merge
```